# How to fix : expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to ask the user about their favorite subject, but I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\BillyG\Documents\Revision\ICT\Challenge 5.py", line 2, in 
>   module
>
> favesub = input("Hello what is your favourite subject", firstname, "?")
>
> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

The code is:

```
firstname=input("What is your name: ")
favesub = input("Hello what is your favorite subject", firstname, "?") 
print ("I love ", favesub, "aswell")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` expects a single string, so unlike `print`, where you can append multiple arguments and the string will be parsed as is, you have to format the string yourself. For Python 3.6 and higher, user `input(f"Hello what is your favourite subject {firstname}?")` or `input("Hello what is your favourite subject {}?".format(firstname))` if you're using an older version of Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` only takes one argument, but you're providing 3.

Try

```
input(f"Hello what is your favourite subject {firstname}?")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the strings simply using `+` while asking for user input in the second line. Currently you are passing it three arguments separated by a comma.

```
firstname=input("What is your name: ") 
favesub = input("Hello what is your favourite subject " + firstname + "?") 
print ("I love ", favesub," aswell")

# What is your name: Donald
# Hello what is your favourite subject Donald?Politics
# I love  Politics  aswell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`favesub = input("Hello what is your favourite subject"+firstname+"?")`

Answer (score 0):

problem here is that input() method can only take atmost one argument, whereas you are passing 1.

```
firstname   = input("What is your name: ")
message     = "Hello what is your favourite subject "+firstname+" ?"
favesub     = input(message) 
print ("I love ",favesub," aswell")
```